# Windows 10 restarts automatically

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, event-viewer

Since around a week my Windows starts automatically from hibernation. In the Event-Viewer I've found an event "NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\rempl\shell" which reactivates Windows. This event is triggered around 10:00 every day and will execute "%ProgramFiles%\rempl\remsh.exe.

I would like to know what exactly this program does and if it's useful and how I can make it stop to reactivate my PC everyday.

Comment: I'm not certain what rempl and remsh are, but I've seen similar behavior from Windows Update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's reliability improvements related files. 
According to this Microsoft official document:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/4023057/update-to-windows-10-versions-1507-1511-and-1607-for-update-reliability

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why this needs to be run every day at 10:00 and if it's ok to not letting it reactivate the PC?

Comment: Yes, you can disable it.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same problem and since it is unclear for me what is the effect of its disable, I took a more defensive approach by just not allowing the task to wake up the computer:

[image: Disable wake up]